# Dual OS PC boots into Windows instead of GRUB

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10

I have already asked this question but have gotten no helpful answer. I recently, for fun, tried to take an old computer, format it, and install a dual OS (Windows 10 Home and Ubuntu 16.04) I successfully got both of them installed and running, but to switch between them, I have to use the device's boot selector instead of Ubuntu's convenient grub interface. It does show, but not on boot-up. See the image below for the exact boot order.

[image: Boot Order]

No matter what I do, I can't get it to show grub on boot-up. I've tried changing the EFI within Ubuntu (it resets after restart), changing within Windows (no option), changing from BIOS (no option), reinstalling grub like 3 times (no effect) and everything else. Can someone please help me get grub to show on the first startup?

Here is the output of `sudo parted -l`:

```
Model: ATA ST750LM022 HN-M7 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 750GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 
Number  Start   End    Size    File system     Name                          Flags
 1      1049kB  524MB  523MB   ntfs            Basic data partition          hidden, diag
 2      524MB   629MB  105MB   fat32           EFI system partition          boot, esp
 3      629MB   646MB  16.8MB                  Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 4      646MB   393GB  393GB   ntfs            Basic data partition          msftdata
 5      393GB   744GB  351GB   ext4
 6      744GB   750GB  6328MB  linux-swap(v1)
```

I checked, both Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 are in UEFI.
I have tried changing the boot order/file within Windows too, but it does nothing.
Ubuntu doesn't show up as an option within BIOS, just "OS boot manager"
I have disabled hibernate and fast boot within Windows.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Edit: I FINALLY got boot repair working. http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/hsRxPy4TyH

Comment: What brand/model system. Some need work arounds, or booting fallback/hard drive entry, not ubuntu entry in UEFI boot menu. Have you updated UEFI from vendor? All systems need that. Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: Everything?  Did you try dropping into an EFI shell and setting the boot order there?

Comment: How do i do that... I have never heard of that...

Comment: You could boot into Ubuntu and run `sudo update-grub`, reboot and hope for the best. But as boot-repair did not work,  I'm not sure this will either. But it's worth a try. I would read line 963 onwards of your pastebin, particularly lines 977/78. Make sure you read up about about **bcdedit** first or you could screw up your Windows boot also.  Backup your Windows  bcd file first, just in case.

Comment: just to be sure, do you disable the "Fastboot" mode in the BIOS option? Because it will skip the GRUB and start the default OS (windows)

Comment: Paul Benson, I will try that. Also, both are fresh installs and I have a bootable Linux and Windows USB so I don't mind corrupting data since there is none there. damadam, fast boot isn't in the bios, but I disabled it.